# Artificial Neural Network training for an Automatic Voltage regulator

Tags: matlab

```
I = out.input';
T = out.output';
net=newff(minmax(I),[3,5,1],{'logsig','tansig','purelin'},'trainlm');
net = init(net);                     % Used to initialize the network (weight and biases)
net.trainParam.show =1;     % The result of error (mse) is shown at each iteration (epoch)
net.trainParam.epochs = 10000;       % Maximum limit of the network training iteration process  
net.trainParam.goal =1e-12;          % Stopping criterion based on error (mse) goal
net=train(net,I,T);                % Start training the network
```

I have this code, on matlab r2022b and I already have a simulink file for my output. But when I ran it, it showed me this error:
Error using minmax
Data is not a matrix or cell array.

```
Error in untitled2 (line 3)
net=newff(minmax(I),[3,5,1],{'logsig','tansig','purelin'},'trainlm');
Please help me understand how to fix this issue.
```

I have using different ANN codes that doesn't use a simulink simulation for data that ran fine, but for whatever reason this code showed this error.